# How to access another function of package main in another file?

Tags: go

this is my file tree:

```
.
├── float.go
└── main.go
```

main.go:

```
package main

func main(){
    Float()
}
```

float.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Float(){
    fmt.Println( "hello world")
}
```

when I try to compile the main.go, it throws an error

> command-line-arguments ./main.go:4:2: undefined: Float

Why can't I use the function defined in another file of same packages?

Comment: If you break your `main` package into multiple files, you have to list all when running it: `go run main.go float.go`

Comment: as @icza has mentioned try running `go run *.go` when you have multiple files.

Comment: [`go run` is a toy](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13440). As soon as you have something non-trivial (and a package with more than one source file qualifies) you should switch to `go build` or ` go install`.

Answer (score 1):

As package `main` is split into multiple files, you have to pass all the files to the go compiler when building.

Either you could list it one by one like

```
go run main.go float.go
```

or you could

```
go run *.go
```